# keyboard input from string

Tags: java, string

I have this code

```
 System.out.println("Enter surname to search for:");
 String choice2;
 choice2= sc.nextLine();
```

In my opinion, this should work, but for some reason the program is not pausing to wait for the user to enter  surname, the next line of code is executed exactly after it. Is something wrong with this code please?

Comment: what is sc? it would be a lot easier to help if you would post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: are you pressing enter key after "Enter surname to search for:" is diplsayed on your console?

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

um sscce?

Comment: it is linked, click on it [sscce](http://sscce.org) :)

Comment: You cannot input keyboard from string. I think you have mangeled your question intentionally to avoid closure by duplicate (I am sure there are million answers to the real question, how to input a string from keyboard).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29

Comment: @dinesh707, this enters a string from scanner, not keyboard from string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct , and already wait until the user enter the name ,
 but this code will not pausing in case of you press the Enter key before you enter the name because you use **sc.nextLine()** , but **sc.next()** will wait you until you enter the text

Comment: @user1928374 if this answer helped you,you should upvote and accept.